# Create DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a function

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
            var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
            $("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
                var sp = $(this).text(); 
                var sp1 = sp.split(' ');
                $.each(sp1, function (i, l) {
                    if (l == htext) {
                        var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + htext + "</div>";
                        $(document).append(boldText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I updated the code but no luck.
Here in this code I need to create a l has a DOM element to apply color yellow to that.

please can any body help me out how to create a dom element.

Thanks

Comment: sp1 is the just var, I am just spliting the value of sp. I am getting some string ex: "I love jquery" sp1 is I, love , jquery.

Comment: you cannot apply css to individual words....

Comment: You're trying to highlight some words, but simple text cannot have CSS styles. You'll have to put a `<span>` around each word, and for that, [this jQuery forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/wrapping-specific-words-inside-span-elements) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand where does `l` is in your current code. Anyway, you can create a DOM element with jQuery like this: `var myel = $('<div class="someclass"></div>')`. Then you can append `myel` to wherever you want in the DOM using function like `.appendTo()`, `.after()`, etc.

**EDIT**

You seem to be trying to highlight some words inside an `<option>` element. I have doubts if that is going to work on all browsers, since form elements are a little tricky when it comes to CSS. You can try something like this (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
        var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
        $("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
            var sp = $(this).text();
                var re = new RegExp("\\b" + htext + "\\b")
                sp = sp.replace(re, '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>', "gi");
                $(this).html(sp);
        });
    });
});
```

You also need some CSS on your page, defining the style for `.highlighted`

**UPDATE AFTER CHAT**

I got something working using a `<p>` instead of `<option>`, to rule out the problem of form element styling:

http://jsfiddle.net/GTydh/3/

The updated js (in case fiddle is deleted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
        var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
        //$("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
        $("p").each(function () {
            var sp = $(this).text();
            var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + htext + ")\\b")
            var sOpen = "<span class='highlight'>";
            var sClose = "</span>";
            var newhtml = sp.replace(re, sOpen + "$1" + sClose, "gi");
            $(this).html(newhtml);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks bfavaretto, here in the each loop i get l $.each(sp1, function (i, l) {
                if (l == htext) {
                    $(l).css('color', 'yellow');
                }
            });

Comment: Yes, but them `l` is a word from the `sp` array, right? You have to wrap that word in a span or something so you can apply the css.

Comment: Please can you update my code bfavaretto. I am little confuse here.

Comment: Updated my answer with a different solution.

Comment: There was an escape problem on my regex, can you try again. Also, do you understand how my solution works? Please try to understand the method I suggest, that is basically a string replacement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3864/discussion-between-user957178-and-bfavaretto)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).append($('<div />').css('color', 'yellow'));
```

That will append a new div with a colour of yellow to the document. If you need to add it to a specific element just use `$('#myselector')` instead of `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple

```
var newEl = $('<div THE_ATTRIBUTES_YOU_WANT></div>');
$('THE_ELEMENT_YOU_WANT_TO_APPEND_OR_ADD').append(newEl);
```

Comment: Or just add the attributes like the post before mine =)

Comment: I can append individual work also right? like in my code I need to append l.

Comment: You can append or prepend alot of elements if you want. 
My english is a little bad to try to explain it =) I'll leave you the links that helped me =) 
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/
http://api.jquery.com/append/
They'r documentation is awesome.