# Generating 'a' tags on the fly using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I have an 'a' list like this:

```
<div  id="page">

 <a href="#">2</a>
 <a href="#">3</a>
 <a href="#">4</a> 

</div>
```

For now I have to set the list as HTML, but since I'm going to use ~500 times 'a' I need it be generated as result of some jquery event.

The total amount of 'a' tags is given by `SomeFunction();`

How can I generate (for instance on .click) the exact amount of 'a' tags given by `SomeFunction();` ?

ps The html numbers should also be generated.

Comment: What have you tried? Looping in regular Javascript and creating and appending DOM elements in jQuery aren't particularly difficult concepts, and there's plenty of information to be found using Google.

Comment: I wouldn't ask if I haven't Googled for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create DOM element with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586896/create-dom-element-with-jquery)

Comment: (Im not that guy if thats what you are saying..??)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will keep them in mind just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `SomeFunction()` simply returns an integer:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var count = SomeFunction();
    var aElements = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        aElements += "<a href=\"#\">" + i + "</a>";
    }

    $("#page").append(aElements);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YakF6/)

**DO NOT call** `append()` **500 times as others have suggested - it will be incredibly slow.**

Comment: Thank you so much, will definitely use this!:) (I have spend day and a half on this..)

Comment: just saw your answer.. string appending isnt the fastest thing either.. look at my solution for details..

Comment: @Baz1nga how is appending an array faster? Even more so, how is calling a function to get the count on each iteration of a for loop more efficient? If performance is the key issue, you shouldn't even be using jQuery for something that could as easily be done accessing the DOM directly. We are not talking about slightly faster, we are talking over twice as fast. See http://jsperf.com/dom-appending

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to wrap all this in jQuery, as it can all be created with ease and more efficiently by accessing the DOM yourself?

```
function SomeFunction( len ) {
    var i,
        a,
        coll = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 1; i <= len; i+=1) {
           a =  document.createElement("a");
           a.href = "#";
           a.appendChild(document.createTextNode( i ));
           coll.appendChild( a );            
        }
   document.getElementById("page").appendChild( coll );
}

    SomeFunction(5);
```

A few things that you **do not** want to be doing:

- Modifying the DOM on each element creation (use document fragments to create a collection), to avoid reflow
- Finding the "page" on each add

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ShvUc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#page').append($('<a>...</a>'));
```

as many times as you need

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  var number = SomeFunction();
  for(var i=0; i<number; i++){
    $('#page').append('<a href="whatever.com">Text here</a>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Returns an array with num links
function createLinks(num) {
  var links = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    links.push($("<a>").attr("href", "#").text(i));
  }
  return links;
}

// When someButton is clicked
$(someButton).on("click", function() {
  // Create as many links as specified by SomeFunction and append them to #page
  $("#page").append(createLinks(SomeFunction()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateAnchors(count){
    var target = $('#page'), str='';
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i+=1){
        str += "<a href='#'>" + i + "</a>";
    }
    target.empty().append(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
​    function getATagCount()
    {
    return 100;
     }


    $("<click on what>").click(function()
    {
       var aArray=[];
    for(var i=0;i<getATagCount();i++)
    {
       aArray.push('<a href="#">'+i+'</a>');
    }   
    $("#page").append(aArray.join(" "));
    })​;​
```

is this what you want?